# mac pkg equivalent for windows to make iTunes files-haring accept folders

Tags: windows, directory, bundle, itunes, file-sharing

I want to use iTunes file-sharing to transfer nearly 78.000 files in a nastest folder structure (5G) to my app. iTunes file-sharing accepts files only, so on the mac I just rename a folder into "package.pkg" or "pakage.rtfd" and voilá. This also has the great advantage that, as soon as all files ar on the iPad, I can use the Objective-C function "moveItemAtPath" instead of copying every single file to it's detination. This saves a lot of time.

Unfortunately Windows recognizes *.pkg and *.rtfd package as normal folder, what they really are. So my only alternative is to use zipped folders. Maybe an *.iso image will work too. But then I loose the advantage of using "moveItemAtPath" and I have to copy every single file to its destination.

So my questions are: Does anybody have a idea how I can get iTunes on Windows to accept folders? Or does anybody know a Windows equivalent for mac's *.pkg folders? Any idea that makes it possible to transfer meny files in one pakage and use "moveItemAtPath" instead of copying every single file would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found! Windows users can use iExplorer!

1. Start iExplorer (available at this URL http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)
2. Connect iOS device to PC using USB cable
3. Find this folder: "Apps" > [YOUR_APP] > "Documents"
4. Drag and Drop the bundle/package into "Documents" folder

Note: A bundle/package on Mac is simply a folder on Windows. There is no need to have any file extension like .pkg on Windows.